# Pardot: associate key/value pairs with a prospect

Tags: pardot

Looking to save some custom data against prospects.

Essentially its key value pairs:

- Link Name = Google
- Link = [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Out of the box you get the following custom field types:
Text /
Number /
Date /
Radio Button /
Checkbox /
Dropdown /
Textarea /
Multi-Select /
Hidden /
CRM User

Cant really see how you could get any of those to work.

I know there is a link to CRM / Salesforce custom object but not all our prospects have a related SF record so don't think I could use that either.

Anyone got any hacks or suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

These are actually links to prepopulated event registration forms.  From the links alone you can not identify what event it is for.

EventA => registrationform.com/form/1/user/3

EventC => registrationform.com/form/4/user/5

EventB => registrationform.com/form/6/user/6

Any prospect can have multiple links and we want to merge them into templates.

I did think about appending an arbitrary query string but seems messy and does not get around the one prospect -> many links.

EventA => registrationform.com/form/1/user/3 **?event=EventA**

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @identigral A prospect is a registrant for events.  Each event has an associated update link that is indistinguishable from another.  Hence wanting a key 'event name' and value 'update link'.  A prospect can have many update links.  I have thought about adding an arbitrary query sting to the link of the event name but that would not satisfy our requirements as I need to save multiple links against a prospect?  Thoughts?

Comment: ...so you want to capture clicks via these update links? [Custom redirects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_content_custom_redirects.htm&type=5) might work - take your event update link and turn it into a tracked URL, multiple tracked URLs are possible. Clicks will become activities attached to the prospect.

Comment: @identigral thank you for thinking about this.  We are not too bothered about tracking them, more that we need to store many links against the prospect and the fact that from the link alone you can not identify what event it is associated to.  I have updated the question

Comment: Custom redirect could work. While it can be used to track clicks (if clicked), the mere creation of a custom redirect and associating with a campaign (your event) in Pardot gets you nearly there. To tie the redirect to a prospect, you'd have to perform the click in e.g. Javascript. An easier but hackier option is to use a custom field of type Multi-Select Picklist. It can store (and allow to associate with a prospect) multiple key/value pairs as Value and Label pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Pardot native capabilities.

To accomplish this, you would need an external codebase to detect when the emails need to be sent, update "placeholder custom fields" (which are included in your email merge template) and then send the email. (I also really like clearing the fields after the email is sent to keep a clean record).

I gave a presentation (which was recorded) of this during ParDreamin 2021, which you can watch here if it's helpful: https://pardreamin.com/course-video/how-to-send-a-pardot-email-with-multiple-line-items/